# add class in li after time and re-add from the first

Tags: jquery

i have ul like this

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>        
</ul>
```

i want jquery code

1. 1- add one the first li the
   `current` class
2. after 2 second add on the second li
3. and etc
4. if its the last li re-make from the first

and i will never use a jquery plugin like cycle
because i must do by my hand

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay for delaying. The rest should be obvious from the docs. :)

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
li {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var $list = $('ul li');

    $list.filter(':first').addClass('current');

    setInterval(function() {
        if( $list.filter('.current').index() !== $list.length - 1 ) {
            $list.filter('.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
        }
        else {
            $list.removeClass('current').filter(':first').addClass('current');
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/uQKX6/

Inspired by RightSaidFred:

```
$(function() {
    var $list = $('ul li'),
        tID   = null,
        i     = 0;

    function loop() {
        alert($list.removeClass('current').slice(i, i+1).addClass('current')[0].id);

        if( i < $list.length-1 ) i++;
        else i = 0;

        tID = setTimeout(loop, 2000);
    }

    $list.hover(function() {
        clearTimeout(tID);
    }, function() {
        loop();
    });

    loop();
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/uQKX6/4/

Comment: how i can make it fix when hover on the current one

Comment: if every li has id how i can alert it after each change

Comment: @moustafa: I edited again, also the demo. It's probably not a great idea to `alert()` it, since it's modal, blocking & totally freezing the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lis = $('ul > li');

function switchClass(i) {
    lis.eq(i).removeClass('current');
    lis.eq(i = ++i % lis.length).addClass('current');
    setTimeout(function() { switchClass(i); }, 2000);
}
switchClass(-1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ec63/

Comment: how i can make it fix when hover on the current one